# Google map doesn't show markers

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps

I'm sure this is something so basic, but I've been looking at it for an hour, and I can't see it. I'd appreciate a fresh pair of eyes. This is a pretty basic Google Maps API v3 project, copied almost verbatim from the cookbook, which loads data from a MySQL database into an XML file, and then loads data from the XML file into the map.

Here's 3 sample markers from the XML file:

```
<markers>
<marker name="Total Beverage" type="2" address="9359 Sheridan Blvd Wesminster, CO 80031" lat="-105.053293" lon="39.8658159"/>
<marker name="Union Jack Liquor" type="2" address="1160 S Boulder Road Louisville, CO 80027" lat="-105.1301647" lon="39.9868051"/>
<marker name="Argonaut Wine and Liquor" type="2" address="760 E Colfax  Denver, CO 80203" lat="-104.9785574" lon="39.7398985"/>
</markers>
```

And here's the code that generates the map.

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Big Choice Sample Map</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html { height: 100% }
        body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
        #map { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var customIcons = {
      0: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_yellow.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      1: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      2: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      }
    };

    function load() {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.909939, -105.078369);
      var options = {
        zoom: 12,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      downloadUrl("phpsql_genxml.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var type = parseInt(markers[i].getAttribute("type"));
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lon")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b>";
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            title: name,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    //]]>

  </script>

  </head>

  <body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="load()">
    <div id="map" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

The map centers at the right spot, and zooms to the right level, but the markers don't show up. Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: I'll admit that I'm still pretty bad about variable scope in javascript, but try removing `var` in front of `map`.  I typically leave my map as a global variable.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?  Can you see if the URL for the XML is getting called?

Comment: Josh, no console errors; and the XML is available in the console, so it's being imported correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the latitude and longitude backwards in your xml:

```
lat="-105.053293" lon="39.8658159"
```

Your map is centered at :

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(39.909939, -105.078369);
```

Comment: Apparently, I'm an idiot. They were geocoded originally backwards. Thanks for your sharp eyes.